# Will passengers get on at bus depots?

Tags: cities-in-motion-2

It seems like it would be really convenient and efficient if bus depots also functioned as bus stops for getting on/off, so passengers could transfer there. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depots exist purely as a point for purchasing vehicles, route line start & end points, and vehicle maintenance. **They do not allow passengers to "wait" at them**. This function would be nice, but that's just not how they work at the moment.

[image: Depot]